# On which target platforms does GCC not support dollar signs in identifiers?

Tags: c, gcc

Dollar signs in identifiers are not strictly conforming to the C standard, but are a widely implemented extension. The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html) says:

> In GNU C, you may normally use dollar signs in identifier names. This is because many traditional C implementations allow such identifiers. However, dollar signs in identifiers are not supported on a few target machines, typically because the target assembler does not allow them.

In my own testing, I have found GCC supports them for Linux on x86, x86-64, PPC64, z/Arch, 32-bit ARMv7, and 64-bit ARM; 32-bit and 64-bit x86 Windows (compiling with MinGW); and 32-bit and 64-bit macOS (by which I mean OS X, not Classic MacOS). Separately I tested clang, and found it supports them on all the above platforms too. I haven't actually come across any platform on which dollar signs in identifiers don't work. What are the target platforms on which dollar signs in identifiers are not supported?

Comment: Generally go through [GNU assembler documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.34/as/index.html). From what I found, ex. on Z80 `$` is used for hex number, on VAX `$` is used as immediate character. Etc.

Comment: @KamilCuk I would be surprised if dollar sign were unsupported in identifiers on VAX, given how heavily dollar sign identifiers are used in the VMS API. Hence, the approach you are proposing may produce incorrect results.

Comment: Most assembly languages use $ for hex notation. Why that would block non-standard C identifiers out, I'm not sure. This should be part of the (non-standard) compiler, not the port.

Comment: Notably `clang -std=c11 -pedantic-errors` block dollar signs, unlike gcc. Probably this is not gcc's intention, since it usually disables non-standard extensions when compiling in strict mode.